# Sending array of string from postman client

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I am using web api with identity 2.0.
I want to assign multiple roles to a user.
I am using post man client to communicate with web api.
In api the method i used to get user id and roles for the user is given below:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddRoleToUser(string userid,[FromUri] string[] selectedRoles)
```

Here selectedRoles is an array.
From postman client i am passing array as given below :
[image]

I am passing user id in the url.
Am i passing the array of roles in correct format from postman client?
The call to api was success ,but selectedRoles always contains null value.
I tried with raw json as given below,but it did not worked

[image]

If i can pass the roles as raw json,can any show an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: you're specifying that `selectedRoles` array comes from the URI (URL) with this attribute: `[FromUri]`. You need to remove this attribute, because you're sending it in the request body, not in the URL.

Web API actions can only receive a single parameter from the request body, and any number of parameters from the URL. So you need to pass the `userid` parameter as a query string parameter, like this `?userid=123123`, and the other parameter in the body. (You could also create a route that includes a `userid`, or receive the `userid` as the `id` parameter and pass it as an URL segment, if you're using the deafult route)

You also need to specify in your headers the format of the information you're sending in the body. So you need to include this header: `Content-Type: application/json`, because you're including JSON in your request body.

Finally, as you're sending a single parameter from the body, you can send it like this:

```
['Admin', 'Employee']
```

If you want to use the format in your example, you shuould create a class to use as parameter in your action, that would look like this:

```
public class RoleList
{
   public string[] selectedRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And your action should include this as parameter:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> 
     AddRoleToUser(string userid, RoleList roleList)
```

Answer (score 2):

method code in C#:

```
    public void Put([FromBody]string[] selectedRoles)
    {
        foreach (var role in selectedRoles)
        {

        }
    }
```

to call method in postman

in heading tab add your parameter and     **Content-type**     parameter with value     **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

in body tab select    **raw** and **JSON(application/json)**
then in body box add your array like below:
**['Admin', 'Employee']**